# jQuery Drag + Drop With Pyramid + Ajax

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, pyramid

I have created some working jQuery code using the [redips.net table drag and drop table rows](http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-row/).

I have this working in my templates how it needs to, but now on "save" I need to generate a JSON string for the data I have moved around, and then write it to my database (easy enough) but what I need help with is how to extract the data from my web page so it can then be saved into my database.

My current template is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/redips-drag-min.js"></script>
<div id="drag">
{% for vehicle in vehicles %} <!-- List the vehicles available -->
<table class="listing" id="{{ vehicle.id }}">
<colgroup><col width="100"/><col width="120"/><col width="480"/><col width="100"/><col width="100"/></colgroup>
<tr>
<th class="mark">{{ vehicle.reg }}</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<div id="drag">
{% for vehicle in vehicles %} <!-- List the vehicles available -->
<table class="listing" id="{{ vehicle.id }}">
<colgroup><col width="100"/><col width="120"/><col width="480"/><col width="100"/><col width="100"/></colgroup>
<tr>
<th class="mark">{{ vehicle.reg }}</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="mark">  </th>    
<th class="mark">Account #</th>
<th class="mark">Customer</th>
<th class="mark">Order #</th>
<th class="mark">Order Weight</th>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td class="rowhandler"><div class="drag row"></div> </td> 
<td></td> 
<td></td> 
<td></td>  
<td></td>
</tr>
<!-- want items to be dropped as rows in here -->
</table>
{% endfor %}

<table class="listing">
<colgroup><col width="100"/><col width="120"/><col width="480"/><col width="100"/><col width="100"/></colgroup>
<tr>
<th class="mark">Collections</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="mark">  </th>    
<th class="mark">Account #</th>
<th class="mark">Customer</th>
<th class="mark">Order #</th>
<th class="mark">Order Weight</th>
</tr>   
{% for order in orders %}
<tr> 
<!-- rows should be able to get dropped into any vehicle table -->
<td class="rowhandler"><div class="drag row"></div> </td> 
<td>{{ order.oh_custaccref }}</td> <!-- and then into any other table (if required) -->
<td>{{ order.name }}</td> 
<td>{{ order.oh_orderno }}</td>  
<td>{{ order.oh_orderwgt }}</td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}    
</table>

</div> <!-- end drag -->

<form id="myform">
    <ol id="drop_list">
    </ol>
    <input id="save_button" type="button" value="Save" class="button" onclick="redips.save()" title="Save form"/>
</form>
```

So what I need help with is how to get the data from these tables into a JSON string so I can manipulate it with Pyramid. I haven't been able to find anything that directly helps me with this, I have very basic JavaScript/jQuery knowledge (as well as AJAX) so I apologise if I have attempted this the wrong way or produced messy code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easiest would be to move your table inside the form tag and add a hidden input with a unique ID to each row:

```
<td>{{ order.oh_custaccref }} <input type="hidden" name="row_id" value="{{ order.oh_custaccref }}"</td>
```

then, when you submit the form (no JavaScript trickery required), the row_ids will be sent in the order they are present in your table. In your form submit handler, you'll be able to get those values using

```
row_ids = request.GET.getall('row_id')
```

(See [MultiDict](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/narr/webob.html#multidict) for explanations).

This approach does not send JSON to the server, just the normal form submit, but it allows you to minimize usage of JavaScript/jQuery/AJAX which you're not very familiar with.

Comment: Thanks that sounds a lot better, only thing is I don't think with this I can work out what tables the rows are coming from. E.g How can I split the rows down into their new tables? Would I have to use javascript on a hidden input to get table id where the rows reside?

Comment: @Crooksey: Hmm, I was thinking about re-arranging the rows of a single table using drag-and-drop. It appears you're doing something more complicated. Can you explain your use case in more details?